# Certain roles creating users

Tags: users

I am spinning up a site that will have 18 different organizations interacting together.  Each organization has a president with access to specific forms and parts of the site.  I would like them to be able to create/add users from their own organization.

Where I am stuck is that each president should only be able to edit/remove users from his own organization (aka that he created).  Do I need to create 18 different roles for each president and 18 different roles for members from their organizations, or is there a more convenient way of managing this.

I have reviewed the following modules without success:
Protect_critical_users, role_delegation, administerusersbyrole

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need not to create different roles for each user but one user role will serve the purpose with help of [SUBUSER](https://drupal.org/project/subuser) module.
Though it's in alpha stage for D7 but it has served me well for a project where I am handling organization as users.
You will need to give proper permission though, I hope you can play with that.

Comment: I have it enabled, but I can't find where to actually allow the user to create the subusers.

Comment: You should check permission & if it's enable for any user type(for superadmin permission is given), you will find subuser tab at my account page..